# lambda expression under g++ compiler in linux

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, lambda, g++

i need to to use c++ find_if() lambda expression, in my vc compiler it compiles without any errors, and i can't compile it in linux:debian:g++4.4 :

-CPP function:

```
    istream_iterator<string> it = find_if(istream_iterator<string>(ss),
        f,
        [=](const string& str)
        {return str == to_string(urlHash);});
```

-Error output:

```
    -error: expected primary-expression before '[' token
    -error: expected primary-expression before '=' token
    -error: expected primary-expression before ']' token
    -error: expected primary-expression before 'const'
```

**question 1** : is this a version related problem of c++, despite using the -std=c++0x flag, nothing changes.

**question 2** : i can't use -std=c++11 flag, despite that i installed the gcc 4.7 in my machine.

thanks;

Comment: Lambdas got introduced in gcc4.5 afair.

Comment: @Malloc how can i update to 4.5 or higher in debian

Comment: Do you receive the same error using an [online compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916000/online-c-compiler-and-evaluator), most support C++11 ... [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) makes it simple to adjust the flags and has `g++-4.6` to `g++-4.8` as well as `clang++`? If so can you provide a live example from one of them?

Comment: hi @ShafikYaghmour, when i compile my code with visual studio i get no errors, so i guess my code is working.

Comment: @Reda unfortunately the various compilers don't always agree either due to various levels of standards support, errors or extensions. Which is why providing an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is important and a live example is even better.

Comment: @Reda That depends on your system, read the documentation of your package manager.

Comment: i have a Debian, seriously why is it so hard to upgrade a compiler ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **question 1** : is this a version related problem of c++, despite using the -std=c++0x flag, nothing changes.

Yes. Lambdas are not supported in GCC 4.4. You will need to upgrade to or install version 4.5 or higher. See [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) for more details.

> **question 2** : i can't use -std=c++11 flag, despite that i installed the gcc 4.7 in my machine.

That is not a question.

Comment: hi, how can i upgrade to 4.7 please
i'm really new to linux

Comment: @Reda You may have to find an alternative repository or install from source. Be careful not to replace your system gcc and g++ (probably in `/usr/bin/gcc` and `/usr/bin/g++`) with the new version. Install it somewhere else (e.g. `/opt/local`), and call that version explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

if you guys interested in this i found a way to install gcc-4.7 by building it your self in every linux system
link:

http://gcc.gnu.org/install/