# How to get lambda functions not working on gcc 5+

Tags: c++, gcc, lambda

I am trying to use a very simple lambda function in c++ on my linux machine (running gcc version 5.4.0) but I am getting an error.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>               

int main()                 
{                        
  auto sayHello = [](int a, int b) -> int      
  {     
    return a + b;           
  }; 

  sayHello(55, 66);    
  return 0;    
}
```

`g++ main.cpp -o listener && ./listener -std=c++11`

This works in Visual Studio on windows but, even though lambdas are [supported on gcc 4.5 and higher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23292502/lambda-expression-under-g-compiler-in-linux) I get the error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:      
main.cpp:5:8: error: ‘sayHello’ does not name a type     
   auto sayHello = [](int a, int b) -> int    
        ^              
main.cpp:10:12: error: ‘sayHello’ was not declared in this scope     
   sayHello();
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: If you read the question and answers you linked you'll notice that they mention the `-std=c++11` flag. Figuring out what it does left as an exercise.

Comment: I propose to close as this is a trivial typo/error.

Comment: @Walter I think that is a great idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put `-std=c++11` as one of the flags for `g++`:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o listener && ./listener
```

Right now, you're passing it as a flag for the `./listener` executable.

Comment: Or better yet `-std=c++14` or my personal favorite `-std=c++1z`.

Comment: sayHello(3,4) as sayHello takes to int

Comment: @user1438832 yes! typo sorry.

Comment: @DeiDei I would advise against using interim standard versions in production code. If the standards comittee changes direction (as they did with fold expressions) then versions such as 1z can behave differently to the new proposed standard (as indeed happened with fold expressions and gcc/clang).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is the cause but in your command you are adding the -std=c++11 in the wrong place. It should be a parameter for gcc.